# Unable to display the html table size equally

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am able to float the two tables, one is on the left side and one is on the right side. However, the table size on the left is not symmetrical to the table on the right. I am unable to display the table size equally. What should i do to display the table side by side equally?

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0nhJ.png)

**html file**

```
 <div class="floatleft">
        <div class="left">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">

        <%              
        Connection conn = null;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=1234&password=1234";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
        String sql = "select * from test";
        PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        %>

        </div>          
        </div>

        <div>

        <p<u>Arm</u></a></font></p>

        <table>

        <tr>
        <th >Arm Exercises</th>
        <th >Number of times</th>
        <th colspan='1'>  </th>

        <%

        String sql1="";
        {
            sql1 = "select * from test";
            PreparedStatement pstmt1=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);   
            ResultSet rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next()){

            String id       = rs1.getString("ID");



            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td style = 'width: 85%'>");
            out.println(arm);
            out.println("</td>"); 

        %>

        <td>
        <textarea cols="2"></textarea>
        </td>

        <%
            out.println("</tr>");
                }   
            conn.close();
                }
        %>

        </table><br>
        </div>
```

Comment: Add your html as code to your question please.

Comment: I only see a "left" div and one table in your code. If we are to find why they are not equal / point you in the correct way we really need to see both tables. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the table in the div element with a class name.

```
<div class="floatleft">
<table>
</table>
<div class="floatright">
<table>
</table>
```